# How to convert Column from LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem I have is that the LogonTime column cannot be changed to a DATE type, even when using the CONVERT, CAST, and TRY_CONVERT functions.

I have tried the following functions CONVERT, CAST, TRY_CONVERT, but none of them manage to convert that DATETIME column to DATE. I used conversion to VARCHAR, and what it does is turn it into the name of the month. The column value example: `11/17/2022 10:56:38 PM`, and the value result to convert in VARCHAR: `NOV 17 2022 10:56 AM`. The expected result : `11/17/2022` or `11-17-2022`.

```
SELECT Subquery.*, rl.LogonTime as Logon 
FROM (SELECT su.Name, sg.Name as Security 
    FROM SecUser su
    LEFT JOIN SecGroupChild sgc ON sgc.ChildKey = su.UniqueID
    LEFT JOIN SecGroup sg ON sgc.GroupKey = sg.UniqueID
) AS Subquery
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Username, LogonTime
    FROM RankedLogins
    WHERE RowNum = 1
) 
rl ON rl.Username = Subquery.Name
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so we can advise on the best solution.

Comment: sorry, i have edited the asked

Comment: If the "LogonTime" column really is a "datetime" data-type then you certainly would be able to do CONVERT(date, LogonTime), without the need to worry about any "varchar" conversions in the middle.  Can you confirm exactly what the data-type of the "LogonTime" column is?

Comment: The conversion to varchar formats seems like you're trying to mix presentation concerns into your query - that should be something handled by whatever frontend is consuming this data. If you really must do this in SQL, though, have you read the [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) documentation yet? Seems like `varchar(10)` result with date/time styles 101 or 110 would be what you need.

Comment: Its not clear what your actual question is here, we need further details. Is it literally just converting the datetime to a string date format? If so how does the left join etc have any effect on it? We need a [mre] here i.e. the simplest form of the problem such as the answers show.

Comment: What I meant when I converted it to varchar was to apply the format differently, and as for the results, you can see what happens when I use any function to convert it to a date, or well, to remove the time.
[result with any function to convert](https://postimg.cc/HjwPwXps)
[initial value](https://postimg.cc/1fLkMPky)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have datetime  use `FORMAT`

```
DECLARE @date Datetime
SET @date = '11/17/2022 10:56:38 PM'
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'MM-dd-yyyy')
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 11-17-2022 |

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 11/17/2022 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ebJDBRkr)

Comment: It does generate the result, but in the query, it doesn't display all the dates correctly. In some cases, it leaves them blank. I'm not sure if it's because of the left join or something like that.

Comment: [result with any function to convert](https://postimg.cc/HjwPwXps)
[original value](https://postimg.cc/1fLkMPky)

Comment: screenshots don'  help edit my fiddle and show me your actual query with the wronh result and then link it

Comment: Thank you for the help. I made some modifications, and it did work with this. Thanks, and sorry for not being so clear with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem converting it to desired format, check this -

```
select convert(varchar(16),convert(date,'NOV 17 2022 10:56 AM',103),101)
```

Comment: Should specify the varchar length